Problema con Resource bundle resources.application cannot be found on classpath
En el index.html me da el error

Resource bundle resources.application cannot be found on
classpath

he estado quitando validaciones pero no he conseguido nada

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

¿qué sistema de construcción o tipo de proyecto de eclipse estás usando? ¿En qué carpeta pusiste tu archivo resources.application? tu c+odigo es Java EE o Spring?
